# Creating new record if the id is not in db

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am working on a cakephp 2.x , I want to create a new row or record if the userid is not present in db otherwise update the record,  but the problem is: it is not updating the current record. It is creating the record with the userid "0" I dont know the problem is. If is not finding the record it should create a record with the userid which I am giving.

```
public function activeNoStatus(){


    $this->loadModel('Status');
    $userid =  $this->request->data('idUser');
    $notify =  $this->request->data('notify');

    $data = array();
    $data['activeNo'] = $notify;




    $count =  $this->Status->findUserId($userid);
    if($count>0){
        $this->Status->id = $userid;
        $this->Status->save($data);


        echo "update";
    }else{
             //create new row
          $datanew=array();
         $this->Status->id = $userid;
         $this->request->data['Status']['activeNo']=$notify;

          $this->Status->save($this->request->data);
          echo "ok";
    }



}
```

Comment: Where is the vital `$this->Status->create()` if you want to create a new record?

Comment: ohh i missed here whil;e posting .. nope its working ..it is creating the record with the idUser .... and i do let you know that my idUser which is primary key is not autoincrement

Comment: well thank you it solves my problem ... i was missing that line

Answer (score 0):

It seems idUser field is not autoincrement, In [cakePHP documentaion](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) :

> All tables with which CakePHP models interact (with the exception of
>   join tables), require a singular primary key to uniquely identify each
>   row. If you wish to model a table which does not have a single-field
>   primary key, CakePHP’s convention is that a single-field primary key
>   is added to the table. You have to add a single-field primary key if
>   you want to use that table’s model.
>
> Rather than using an auto-increment key as the primary key, you may
>   also use char(36). Cake will then use a unique 36 character uuid
>   (String::uuid) whenever you save a new record using the Model::save
>   method.

So you should make idUser autoincrement Primary key.